# Http request.getIntHeader() returns a NumberFormat Exception

Tags: java, servlets

I made a Http request and this is how the request header looks like:

```
GET /unni/servlets/servlet/HelloWorldExample HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8700
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

Then, I just used `request.getIntHeader("User-Agent")`.This time I got a `NumberFormatException` saying that 'request header
cannot be converted to an integer'.This is what API and servlet spec also say.I searched for more about this to get some working example, but did not get any desired results.So,how can I use this method? I am using `Apache Tomcat 7.0.25`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Header with key "User_Agent" contain mixed date type value(combination of String and Integer), in your case it is :User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0.

If you trying to get this value as Integer you definitely get NumberFormatException (because header value contain non-numeric value as well).

you can only apply request.getIntHeader() to those header which contain purely numeric value.
you can define your own header key with numeric value and retrieve this using request.getIntHeader().

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I had a misunderstanding that it can apply to all headers until I read your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand, the User-Agent header is a string, you could retrieve it like
 `String userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent");`
Or am I missing the point of your question?

Comment: There is a  method called 'getIntHeader("String")in HttpServletRequest interface apart from normal methods.This will return integer. Please check servlet API for further information

Comment: I know, but quoting the API "Returns the value of the specified request header as an int." The User-Agent is a String, so you should try with what I suggested in the answer.